# KKT conditions and feasibility of problems (P) and (D)

Tags: linear-programming

Let following linear problems:

Primal Problem:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\textrm{Min}\quad    c^T x &   &    \\
\textrm{s.t.}\quad  Ax    & \geq & b   
\end{eqnarray*}
and its dual problem:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\textrm{Max}\quad    b^T \lambda &   &    \\
\textrm{s.t.}\quad  A^T\lambda    & = & c \\
\lambda & \geq & 0 
\end{eqnarray*}

and suppose that (P) and (D) are both feasible. Show that there exist optimal points $X^\star$ and $\lambda ^\star$ such that:

\begin{array}{l}
\textrm{1)}\quad AX^\star \geq b \\
\textrm{2)}\quad A^T\lambda^\star = c \,\, , \,\, \lambda^\star \geq 0 \\
\textrm{3)}\quad (AX^\star-b)\bot \lambda^\star \\
\textrm{4)}\quad AX^\star-b+\lambda^\star >0 
\end{array}